# Heroku: Start a one-off dyno worker from a scheduler

Tags: java, heroku

Is there a way to execute a `heroku run:detached "one-off-task 1"` from within a Heroku application? Goal is to have the task run in a separate dyno but still write logs. In other words: I would like to use the heroku-toolbelt functionality inside a running application to start one-off dynos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Heroku Platform API:

- [Heroku DevCenter: Getting started with Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart)
- [Heroku DevCenter: Platform API Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference)

Specifically under [Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno)

You can use a scheduler process to periodically call the API to spin up a on-off dyno that does the work.